# GLEW in multiple files

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I have a project I've made in Visual Studio. In my main.cpp I have glew initialized, glfw initialized, and everything is working. What I want to know is that if there is a way to call opengl functions in other source files. I have a source file called render_2d.cpp, but I cannot use opengl functions because they are undefined.

That part is pretty obvious to me, but how do I go about using opengl functions in other files? I can't seem to understand how I initialize glew in other files.

Comment: You can't just include the glew header, and call the OpenGL functions? As long as it's initialized once, I don't think you have to initialize it again.

Comment: When I try to include glew.h one function is undefined wglSwapIntervalEXT, but all others seem to be there. Building with glew.c fixes the issue. Should I include glew.c in my render_2d.cpp. I'm using the GLEW_STATIC macro in my main.cpp. Should I use it with render_2d.cpp?

Comment: You can include glew wherever you want in your program if you want access to OpenGL functions; you can also use any GL header file for that purpose too. But, you don't have to initialise GLEW more than once.

Comment: I just tried using glew.h in my render_2d.cpp and everything works fine now. I still wish glew.h would include the function I mentioned. It's just weird to me why it's not in glew.h

Comment: `wglSwapIntervalEXT()` looks like a Windows function. You'll probably need to include `windows.h` for that.

Comment: `glew.h` only covers OpenGL extensions. `wglSwapIntervalEXT` is a WGL extension (all swap extensions are window-system specific). That means you need to bring in the window-system part of GLEW (in this case `wglew.h`, on GLX it is `glxew.h`)